# How can I set the title of a UIButton as left-aligned?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I need to display an email address on the left side of a `UIButton`, but it is being positioned to the centre.

Is there any way to set the alignment to the left side of a `UIButton`?

This is my current code:

```
UIButton* emailBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,30,250,height+15)];
emailBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[emailBtn setTitle:obj2.customerEmail forState:UIControlStateNormal];
emailBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.5];
[emailBtn setTitleColor:[[[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:0.121 green:0.472 blue:0.823 alpha:1]autorelease] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[emailBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(emailAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[elementView addSubview:emailBtn];
[emailBtn release];
```

Comment: For Swift 5.1 you can look my answer     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765024/how-to-set-the-title-of-uibutton-as-left-alignment/65124739#answer-65124739

Answer (score 1678, accepted):

Set the contentHorizontalAlignment:

```
// Swift 
emailBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left;

// Objective-C
emailBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```

You might also want to adjust the content left inset otherwise the text will touch the left border:

```
// Swift 3 and up:
emailBtn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0);

// Objective-C
emailBtn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you can also set both of these properties from Interface Builder.

Comment: so it was number 9000  from me, thanx , useful answer

Comment: We're too lazy to search the documentation. What would we do without SO!

Comment: Goes to show SO is better documented than Apple document.

Comment: Is it possible to use Leading or Trailing rather than Right or Left? (for localisation purposes)

Comment: `UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeading` and `UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentTrailing` were added in iOS 11

Answer (score 125):

You can also use interface builder if you don't want to make the adjustments in code.
Here I left align the text and also indent it some:

[image: UIButton in IB]

Don't forget you can also align an image in the button too.:

[image]

Comment: This helped me out a ton, can't believe I didn't realize that's what those controls were for.

Comment: Thanks, It helped me. I was not able to find out edge insets for button title without the help of arrow indication in your sample pictures.

Comment: in xcode 8.2.1 it moved to other place see my answer below

Comment: How to do that programmatically in swift? I want align image on the right, and title on the left side???

Answer (score 44):

In Swift 3+:

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

Comment: What is the difference between .leading and .left value of contentHorizontalAlignment?

Comment: @jamryu that in case of languages where you write from right to left (arabic I think..?) `.leading` will have same effect as `.right`.

Answer (score 20):

**Swift 4+**

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
button.contentVerticalAlignment = .top
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```

Answer (score 15):

```
UIButton *btn;
btn.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```

Answer (score 10):

Using `emailBtn.titleEdgeInsets` is better than `contentEdgeInsets`, in case you don't want to change the whole content position inside the button.

Answer (score 8):

Here is explained how to do it and why it works so:
http://cocoathings.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-make-uibutton-text-left-or-right.html

Answer (score 7):

in xcode 8.2.1 in the interface builder it moves to:[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is a small error in the code of @DyingCactus.
Here is the correct solution to add an UILabel to an UIButton to align the button text to better control the button 'title':

```
NSString *myLabelText = @"Hello World";
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

// position in the parent view and set the size of the button
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(myX, myY, myWidth, myHeight); 

CGRect myButtonRect = myButton.bounds;
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: myButtonRect];   
myLabel.text = myLabelText;
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14.0];   
myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

[myButton addSubview:myLabel];
[myLabel release];
```

Hope this helps....

Al

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 2.0:

```
emailBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left
```

This can help if any one needed.

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 5.0** and **Xcode 10.2**

You have two ways to approaches

1) Direct approach

```
btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

2) **SharedClass** example (write once and use every ware)

This is your shared class(like this you access all components properties)

```
import UIKit

class SharedClass: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SharedClass()

    private override init() {

    }
}

//UIButton extension
extension UIButton {
    func btnProperties() {
        contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
    }
}
```

In your **ViewController** call like this

```
button.btnProperties()//This is your button
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
button.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft;
```

Comment: This worked for me, contentHorizontalAlignment didn't, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**: Using `UIButton.Configuration` - do `titleAlignment = .center` but also add a subtitle and make its font microscopic.

---

So, we're on iOS 15+, we're using the new `UIButton.Configuration` APIs, buttons now go multi-line by default and you're trying to figure out - how do I make the button's title be centered or trailing aligned, as opposed to the default (leading). For example you have an image and a button title underneath and and you want it centered.

[image]

Seems reasonable to try this:

```
configuration.titleAlignment = .center
```

But it doesn't change anything.

By trying thing out in Interface Builder, I noticed the following: `titleAlignment` only has an effect if there is a subtitle along with the title.

[image]

I am not sure if this is an omission on Apple's side (which might be fixed later) or if there is a good reason for it. In any case, we need a way to make it work without a subtitle. Perhaps some clever `contentInset` or `UIControl.contentHorizontalAlignment` can do the trick, but I'd be worried to use these in cases where we have to think about other languages, dynamic type etc.

Here's a solution which is still hacky, but would do the job:
Add a `subtitle` which contains just a space, then make the font microscopic, e.g. `0.01`.

This is how to do it in code, assuming you are already working with a `UIButton.Configuration`:

```
configuration.titleAlignment = .center
configuration.title = "Hello hi"
configuration.subtitle = " "
configuration.subtitleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer({ input in
    var output = input
    output.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 0.01)
    return output
})
```

Not an ideal solution and it might break in the future, but for some use cases the best available solution at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

if you use `button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)`, you will get an warning that states `'contentEdgeInsets' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: This property is ignored when using UIButtonConfiguration`. An alternative solution is:

**iOS 15.0+**

```
    var button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(configuration: .filled())

        button.configuration?.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 16, leading: 20, bottom: 16, trailing: 20)
        button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .leading
        
        return button
    }()
```