# uibutton text justify

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I am trying to left justify text on a UIButton. It is middle justified by default. The following doesnt seem to work. Can someone suggest what may work.

```
  aButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
```

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765024/how-to-set-the-title-as-left-alignment-in-the-uibutton/2765158#2765158

Comment: Thanks. It works. Can you please put this in an answer so that I can acknowledge it :)

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the label alignment, not the text alignment.

```
aButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```