# How to alignment the text of button to the left?

Tags: iphone, ios

Now I want to alignment  the text of button to the left with code , how to do ?
and I code this :

```
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You have to use `contentVerticalAlignment` and `contentHorizontalAlignment` of the button.

Comment: and I use it:                                button.contentVerticalAlignment = button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentLeft; but it doesn't work,how to use this property?

Comment: OK,I found that:button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill; Thank you!

Comment: Refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2765158/49186). you will change the contentEdgeInsets property as well

Comment: Do you know what .titleLabel.textAlignment is for, then?

Answer (score 26):

Use `ContentHorizontalAlignment` as below

```
btnObj.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```

Answer (score 9):

Swift Code

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using **Swift 3**

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

Above code align text to left border, so you might want little padding.

```
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting to button titleLable alignment also works perfectly.

```
btn.titleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```