# Set a UIButton content alignment in iOS10

Tags: ios, uibutton

Seems to be missing so I can no longer do

[How to alignment the text of button to the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162398/how-to-alignment-the-text-of-button-to-the-left)

I can modify the frame but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
yourButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left; //For horizontal alignment (.center, .left, .right, .fill)
yourButton.contentVerticalAlignment = .center; //For vertical alignment (.bottom, .center, .fill, .top)
```

Also you can set control alignment in the IB.

Comment: UIButton.h has no properties for that. What iOS version are you on?

Comment: It’s a property of UIControl, not UIButton. This properties ​​have been added in iOS SDK 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in IB also. Go in attribute inspector of UIButton set Control

[image]