# Aligning Image and Title in UiButton

Tags: ios, ios5

I wish to align title and image in UiButton in such a manner that the title appears on the left and the image to the extreme right.
Please note that the button is stretched so as to fill the screen horizontally.

The button layout should look something like this:-
[title .. ]

The title should have some left padding.
The image should have some right padding.

```
CGFloat width = self.frame.size.width;
CGFloat imageWidth = [button currentImage].size.width;
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft; 
[button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)];
[button setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, width - imageWidth - 10, 0, 0)];
```

However, though the title is left align, there is a *lot* of space on it's left. The image does not show up at all!

Comment: Please add the code you use to add the image to the UIButton

Comment: [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: you have added button in xib or custom button?

Comment: it's just a uibutton.

Comment: please check out my ans below

Comment: What about `[UIView] > [UILabel + UIImageView] + UITapGestureRecognizer` ?

Comment: Good point. But I did not want to go via that route. I think setImageEdgeInsets and setLabelEdgeInsets should be enough to achieve what I want.

Comment: have a look at this link using UIEdgeInsets too you can align them. http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/07/youre-doing-it-wrong-2-sizing-labels.html

Comment: I added an answer [here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765024/how-to-set-the-title-as-left-alignment-in-the-uibutton]
that explains how to so the image and text alignment with Interface Builder.

Answer (score 5):

Following Code will work

```
UIButton *sectionheader=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
[sectionheader setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,6,0,0)];
sectionheader.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
[sectionheader setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
```

// Now Create Label and addsubview to button

```
UILabel *lblkey=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,sectionheader.frame.size.width-10,sectionheader.frame.size.height)];

lblkey.accessibilityValue=@"Value";
lblkey.font=[UIFont fontWithName:themefont size:20];
lblkey.text=[creteria uppercaseString];
lblkey.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lblkey.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lblkey.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
lblkey.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
lblkey.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[sectionheader addSubview:lblkey];
```

And suppoce you value is going to change always and you want to make it perfect than Make `UIButton` class and than add above code in that category class than just call following method to change value of that label

```
+(void)settitle:(NSString *)value:(UIButton *)selfbutton
{
     for (UILabel *valuelabel in selfbutton.subviews)
     {
         if ([valuelabel.accessibilityValue isEqualToString:@"Value"])
         {
             valuelabel.text=value;
         }
     }   
}
```

[image: privew]

Answer (score 3):

I will go with alternative 
What you can do is add three control in one view. lets say `ParentView`:

```
1) yourButton 
2) yourlable // don't use button title instead use this lable.
3) imageView
```

now make the `ParentView` autosize like below:

[image]

so as `yourButton` will stretched horizontally it will automatically resize `ParentView`. 
From here on you just want to take care about position.

set `yourlable` to extreme left in `parentView` after `yourButton` and set autosize property to:

[image]
so it will always remain to extreme left of `ParentView` 

And set `imageView` position to extreme right in `parentView` and set autosize property to:
[image] so it will always remain to extreme right of `ParentView` 
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

if you have added button in xib and you want to set title and image then you can do it from Attribute inspector.
 in attributeinspector there is an property named Edge. By default it has set content. but there are other two options named as Title and Image.
and exactly below Inset Property is there by which you can set title and image as you want. if you select title then you can set title (move left or right as u want) likewise for image also

Comment: More detailed answer with images here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717219/uibutton-image-text-ios