# how can we set Button title labels exactly at center of both x-axis and y-axis

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am beginner in Ios and i am trying to inserted UIButton on my ViewController

Here i want to insert button "titlelabel" exactly at center of x-axis and center of y-axis and according to my below code button title label coming like below image please help me what should i do for set that "titlelabel" exactly center of x and y axis

### my code:-

```
NextBtn_2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
NextBtn_2.frame = CGRectMake(190, 330, 120, 30);
[NextBtn_2 setTitle:@"NEXT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
NextBtn_2.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:bitter_Bold size:14];
[NextBtn_2 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[NextBtn_2 addTarget:self action:@selector(NextBtn_2_Clicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

NextBtn_2.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[NextBtn_2 setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
[NextBtn_2 setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];

NextBtn_2.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
NextBtn_2.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
NextBtn_2.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"a53129"];

[self.view addSubview:NextBtn_2];
```

[image]

Comment: That label is centered if you consider what it would look like if you had any characters with descenders such as `y` or `p`, etc.

Comment: UIButton title labels are already centered... might be image problem or font problem... change the font name and try again...

Comment: yes that is font problem but i have to set that font that's my requirement

Comment: how can i resolve my above issue

Comment: is there no way for this?

Comment: By default its centered along x & y axis right ?

Comment: yes with out setting font it's working fine but when i set font it's not working i mean not set at center of x and y axiss

Comment: You can also refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765024/how-to-set-the-title-of-uibutton-as-left-alignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below Property of UIButton

```
NextBtn_2.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
NextBtn_2.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

NextBtn_2.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
```

Hope this is work for you.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `titleEdgeInsets` of your button title lable .

```
NextBtn_2.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(CGFloat top, CGFloat left, CGFloat bottom, CGFloat right) ;
```

hope it works for you .