# Remove underline on UIButton in iOS 7

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, ios7.1

Any one know how to remove the `UIButton` underline that appears because of Accessibility?

(I know it's because the user turned on "Button Shapes")

[image]

[image]

How can I remove that programmatically, or by setting some property in Xcode?

Comment: I guess that you set the text of the button with an `NSAttributedString`. Remove the attributed for underlining it.

Comment: Please provide some code that results in underlying button title.

Comment: @Visput dude thats the normal button object as we used less than ios 7.1 all fine but in ios 7.1 make underline....

Comment: @MitsBhadeshiya Removing the underline is a BAD choice. Leave it be. The user wants it. Let them have it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check below `code` :

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[yourBtnHere attributedTitleForState:UIControlStateNormal] mutableCopy];//or whatever the state you want
[attrStr enumerateAttributesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [attrStr length])
                            options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationLongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired
                         usingBlock:^(NSDictionary *attributes, NSRange range, BOOL *stop)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:attributes];
    [mutableAttributes removeObjectForKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName];
    [attrStr setAttributes:mutableAttributes range:range];
}];
```

• With the inspector/IB:
Select your `UIButton`.
Show the `Attributes Inspector`.
The `Text`settings should be in `Attributed`. Select the text, click on the fond item remove the Underlining setting it at `none`.
[image]

Answer (score 17):

Let me get this straight. Apple added an accessibility feature that lets users mark buttons with underlines if they want to.

You want a way to defeat this feature, specifically designed to help people with handicaps use their devices, when the feature is something that the user has to ask for.

Why?

It is very likely not possible using standard buttons. If you did figure out a way to do it, Apple would likely reject your app because it defeats a system function meant to help the disabled.

So the answer is: Don't do that.

Comment: This is an outstanding reply to such a question but it's not a solution to the question. This should be a comment.

Comment: Because there may be cases where seeing underlined buttons is not acceptable even by a visually impaired person. eg: In a custom keyboard, having this setting on, underlines every button on the keyboard which looks bad. Also some people would have enabled button shapes because they like it this way.

Comment: rmaddy, it **is** an answer. The answer is "No. You can't do that."

Comment: Hackish or not (okay, definitely hackish) but `UIButton` instances are sometimes a very handy tool for laying out text and images with flexible alignment and insets. In these cases (where, of course, `userInteractionEnabled` is permanently turned off) it's preferable to not have the underline.

Comment: @villapossu, What? `UIButton`s are hard at laying out text and images! You can't easily place the image on the right, or the text beneath the button.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei right, they're only simple for placing the image to the left – sure there are more hacks for easily aligning a right-side or top image but as said, they're hacks. (Here's my favorite: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32174204/913299) But nowadays I prefer to be a good citizen and lay out my images and titles with `UIImageView`s and `UILabel`s (thanks `UIStackView` for simplifying that).

Comment: @villapossu, I wanted to mention `UIStackView` too.

Comment: For example, if you write a calculator using frameless UIButtons on a pre-drawn background, the underlines look stupid. There is a valid reason to remove the underlines in many contexts.

Answer (score 10):

Set background image to the button.

```
[yourBtnHere setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Main Questions is Remove underline on UIButton in iOS 7 and You answer to set image on button...!!!!

Comment: having the image seems to prevent this behaviour. Its odd, but it works

Answer (score 4):

The "Button shapes" is a new accessibility option in iOS 7.1. If the user want to have this option activated, there is nothing you can do. This is the user's choice.

Comment: I agree that the accessibility setting should be respected for common use cases of UIButton, but there are many specialized uses of UIButton where the underline is not appropriate.  For example a custom keyboard or a calculator.

Answer (score 3):

If button is underlined due accessibility button shape option then you could set button title by using image but not by text. Simply create image where text will be drawn and set it to the button. In this case iOS can't recognize text there and won't insert underline.
You could consider it as hack but not as clear solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't turn off this accessibility feature.

Make a custom UILabel or [UIView with UITapGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660371/how-to-add-a-touch-event-to-a-uiview) if you really want to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

First get `attribute string` from button which has been set.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[yourBtnHere  attributedTitleForState:UIControlStateNormal] mutableCopy];
```

Remove Attribute using `removeAttribute` like this :

```
[attrStr removeAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName range:NSMakeRange(0,[attrStr length])];
[attrStr addAttribute: NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value: [NSNumber numberWithInt:0] range: [attrStr length]];
```

Reset attribute using `addAttribute` like this:

```
UIColor *textBtncolor = [UIColor blackColor];
[attrStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:textBtncolor range:NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length)];
```

Now set attribute string in your button

```
[yourBtnHere setAttributedTitle:[attrStr copy] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```