# Changing the UIImage position programmarically

Tags: swift, uiimage, position

I have a UITableView with sections. I added a UImage in each cell, but it is on the left side, how can I change it to make it go to the right side?

this is my code for each cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cells")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.section].subType[indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .right
    cell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "GESSTwoLight-Light", size: 15)
    cell!.isUserInteractionEnabled = false;
    cell!.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "username.png")

    return cell!
}
```

[This is my UITableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGRxe.png)

Comment: what you can do is create a tableView custom cell and design it as you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you simply have to do the following in the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method:

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
cell.textLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
cell.imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
```

This will create the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqVSF.png)

Credits goes to [liau-jian-jie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4773291/liau-jian-jie) for [sharing this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32174204/11101923), which also can be applied to UIButtons.