# How to show the title under the UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage

I have used the title inset to display the text name under the `UIButton`.

Here's my code and the output:

```
 [button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 0, 0, 0)];
```

[image]

Here's my expected output:

[image]

I have used the `UIButton` and set the title and `UIImage` as background. So how to show the title label under the `UIButton`?

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2516108/437146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Select button in xib first. then select Attribute Inspector, in this Select Title in "Edge" and set appropriate "Inset" as per Requirements.

please take a look with below code and set insets as per your Requirements.

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40);
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:@"Rate us on app store" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 50, 2, 20)];//set ur title insects myButton
[myButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, -200, 2, 2)];//make negative edge for left side
[myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[self.view myButton];
```

Comment: I'm doing it programmatically . Can you please advice on that ?

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is correct; you just need to set the inset edges as done below. Then you need to increase your button frame so that it can hold the title and image in the same time.

```
[button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 0, 0, 0)];

[button setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.f, button.titleLabel.frame.size.height, 0.f)];
```

This can also be done via storyboards as @VD Patel suggests that is up to you which approach you prefer.

You could also do this with a separate `UIImageview` and a button that would be easier to handle and would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `UIImageView`,`UILabel` and `UIButton`. And later add ImageView and Label as subview to Button.

```
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 200, 100)];
    lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [lbl setText:@"Mono"];

    UIImageView * imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image.png"];
    [imgView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn addSubview:imgView];
    [btn addSubview:lbl];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 200, 300)];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(OnButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Try adding this code in viewDidLoad Method.