# Align button image to right edge of UIButton

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uiimage, uiedgeinsets

There are plenty of threads about aligning a button image according to the title text, but I can't find anything about just aligning the image to the right side of the button.

This has no effect:

```
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 50);
```

How can one right-align the image for a button? Can it be done in the Storyboard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone UIButton - image position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515998/iphone-uibutton-image-position)

Comment: if you are targeting iOS 9 you can [do it like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32014907/1219956)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I don't care about the title text. I just want the image to be right aligned to whatever the frame of the button is.

Comment: @Fonix I need to support iOS 8.

Answer (score 66):

Semantic: Force Right-to-Left on View works for me [image]

Comment: Thanks Man!! Working like a charm for me!!

Comment: Do not use this if you have support for accessibility, because this brakes the order of the elements spoken out by VoiceOver on the screen.

Answer (score 28):

I found a tricky way
Update the constrains for the `UIImageView` of the Button

try this

```
button.imageView?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
button.imageView?.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
```

but don't forget to add this to make the constrains effective

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Comment: EZ. Thanks. Tried checking if the imageView of the UIButton has already constraints but found none. This is the last option if you want your imageView to stick on a certain side of your button without being depended on the title.

Comment: Nice idea simon

Answer (score 20):

There are several different options to do it.

**Use `semanticContentAttribute`**

```
button.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

You can set semantic attribute from interface (storyboard) layout also.

[image]

or
 **Use UIView containing UIButton and UIImage**, as shown in this snapshot.

- Set Image right side in UIView and disable user interaction, so user action/tap will be passed to button.
- Add button with size same as UIView, in UIView, with transparent background color and covering Image.
- Set content offset for button as shown in this snapshot.

[image]

This will make easy to handle button action, properties and customise image position & size according to your requirement. Try this.

Comment: Is there a way to define a padding to complement the `semanticContentAttribute` property? Based on the text in my button, the image could be touching the text, or be far away from it.

Answer (score 17):

**Storyboard**:

Attributes Tab > Ensure your Content Edge tab is selected for 'image':

[image: 1]

Then you alter the 'Left' property not right, which is what your doing programatically. So in other words, your padding it n from the left

UIEdgeInsetsMake = TOP | LEFT | BOTTOM | RIGHT

**Programmatically :**

```
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 100, 0, 0);
```

Note: you might have to also alter your titles inset, depending on where it is in reference to your image

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This indents the image from the left. In other words, with all 4 values at 0, the image is left-aligned. If I increase the "left" inset value, the image moves away from the left edge. This doesn't help because I need the image pinned to the right edge, so that no matter how wide the button stretches, it stays right-aligned.

Comment: @soleil right. As far as I know that can't be down with a system button, but what do I know really. I just used that because that's what you gave as an example as something you've tried. You are right, not a good workaround for various widths, but fine for static widths.

Comment: Well actually. @soleil just make the left inset `self.button.frame.size.width - widthOfImage` or something.

Comment: @soleil nope. Disregard. Wishful thinking. That will probably only work for left aligned content. Yours is most likely centered like everyone else.

Comment: @soleil. Yeah try that. I'm bout to go to bed but try aligning the content to left in storyboard then set the left inset to the one mentioned above. Sounds right

Answer (score 16):

Try below code:

```
btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = .right
```

Comment: the OP is asking how to have the image come after the text, that's what they mean by aligning the image to the right edge of the button. This only aligns the image and text towards the right, but it doesn't have the effect the OP wanted. If you look at the other answers you'll understand what they're trying to do

Answer (score 13):

**Clean way to do this in Swift**

```
button.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 10):

**Simple way**

Using extension to set image on the right side with custom offset

```
   extension UIButton {
    func addRightImage(image: UIImage, offset: CGFloat) {
        self.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        self.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.imageView?.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        self.imageView?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -offset).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Code did not work for me as is. Needed to add
`self.imageView?.contentMode = .right`
to prevent image from being stretched.

Answer (score 5):

make it as default semantic i.e unspecified or force left to right

and in button.imageEdgeInsets set it as

UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: self.view.frame.size.width - (the image size + the alignment space ) , bottom: 0, right: 0)

this will make ensure that no matter what the view size is ,it will always align the image from right side of the button

Comment: *force right to left  and by alignment space i meant some constant say 10.0 so it wont be hugging to the left corner of the view

Comment: Nice and simple.

Answer (score 4):

It's working for me:

```
self.acceptButton.setImage(UIImage(named: image), for: UIControl.State.normal)
self.acceptButton.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
self.acceptButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 9, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like this:

```
btn.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
btn.imageView?.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
btn.imageView?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
btn.imageView?.contentMode = .right
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using UIButton Extension for image to right side**

```
extension UIButton {
    func imageToRight() {
        transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
        titleLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
        imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
    }
}
```

**How to Use**

```
yourButton.imageToRight()
```

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 15.0 you can simply use [the new configuration API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration/) to specify the [image placement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration/3750791-imageplacement), in this case: [trailing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsdirectionalrectedge/3200194-trailing). If you need to support earlier versions, another way of doing this could be by appending an [NSTextAttachment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextattachment/) (available since iOS 7.0) to an NSMutableAttributedString and use that as the button's title.

It is a bad idea to use the semantic content attribute for this, as suggested in other responses, and force it to right-to-left. That API is not meant for that use-case and can have unintended consequences. In this case, it breaks accessibility, especially navigation using VoiceOver. The reason is that if you are swiping to the right to get to the next element in the screen, and that element is forced to be right-to-left, VoiceOver will also reverse and if you swipe right again it will go to the previous element instead of the next one. If you swipe right again, you are back to the right-to-left element. And so on, and so on. The user gets stuck in a focus trap and it can be very confusing.

So the code could look something like this:

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
    let image = UIImage(systemName: "applelogo")
    configuration.image = image
    configuration.imagePadding = 8.0
    configuration.imagePlacement = .trailing
    button.configuration = configuration
    button.setTitle("Apple", for: .normal)
} else {
    let buttonTitle = "Apple"
    let titleAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: buttonTitle + " ")
    let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment(image: UIImage(systemName: "applelogo")!)
    let textAttachmentAttributedString = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)
    titleAttributedString.append(textAttachmentAttributedString)
    button.setAttributedTitle(titleAttributedString, for: .normal)
    // When using NSTextAttachment, configure an accessibility label manually either
    // replacing it for something meaningful or removing the attachment from it
    // (whatever makes sense), otherwise, VoiceOver will announce the name of the
    // SF symbol or "Atachement.png, File" when using an image
    button.accessibilityLabel = buttonTitle
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A button has 2 subviews (this is not true, It has more but whatever, we can consider only 2): the first one is the image; after the image there is a title label. So the image is on the left and the title on the right.

First at all I'm going to show what I'm trying to get: a button with a text on the left side and an image on the right side. I'm trying to switch the button's subviews positions.

The following image is what I'd like to obtain:

[image]

This is how I reach the goal:

1 - Add the title and image to the button:

```
self.myButton.setTitle("My Button Title", for: .normal)
self.myButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right"), for: .normal)
```

[image]

2 - Set horizontal content aligment to left:

```
self.myButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

[image]

3 - Set semantic content attribute from right to left: This means that the leading is going to be the right side of the button and the trailing is going to be the left side of the button. So the image (that's the first view of the button) is going to be at the right side of the button.

```
self.myButton.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

[image]

4 - Add the Button's image constraints in order to repositionate it to the right side (In this case near the leading side, remember that we switch sides when setting the semantic content attribute from right to left):

```
self.myButton.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.myButton.imageView?.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.myButton.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
self.myButton.imageView?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.myButton.leadingAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
```

[image]

That's all folks!

Answer (score 1):

To align an image to right, the 'Semantic' option seems the best, 'Force Right-to-Left'.
Furthermore, I want to add one more thing. You can keep the shape of the button's image by this option.
[image: User Defined Runtime Attributes]

Answer (score 1):

iOS 15: imageEdgeInsets and titleEdgeInsets are deprecated, and also ignored, we have to adjust by our own.

For example, I want to set the title at the beginning of the button and image at the end.

```
extension UIButton {
    func adjust() {
        guard let imageView = self.imageView else { return }
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        
        guard let titleLabel = self.titleLabel else { return }
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        titleLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    }
}
```

You can also put the code in layoutSubviews if subclass UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me by setting:

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
```

Then for the inner image I set the right inset to 0.

```
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 5**

```
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: (bounds.width - 16), bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

With new `UIButton.Configuration` you can use custom background view

```swift
extension UIButton {
  class BackgroundImageView: UIView {
    private let imageView = UIImageView()
    private let imagePlacement: NSDirectionalRectEdge

    init(icon: UIImage? = nil, imagePlacement iconPlacement: NSDirectionalRectEdge = .leading) {
      imagePlacement = iconPlacement
      super.init(frame: .zero)
      imageView.image = icon
      addSubview(imageView)
      layout()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func layout() {
      imageView.snp.remakeConstraints { make in
        make.size.equalTo(24)
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        if imagePlacement == .trailing {
          make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-CGFloat.spacing6)
        } else {
          make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(CGFloat.spacing6)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this example I am using `SnapKit` but you can go for regular auto layout constraints.

usage:

```swift
extension UIButton.Configuration {
  static func config(
    title: String? = nil,
    icon: UIImage? = nil,
    baseBackgroundColor: UIColor,
    baseForegroundColor: UIColor,
    pinIconToEdge: Bool = true
  ) -> Self {
    var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
    config.title = title
    if pinIconToEdge {
      config.background.customView = UIButton.BackgroundImageView(
        icon: icon?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
      )
    } else {
      config.image = icon
      config.imagePlacement = .trailing
      config.imagePadding = .spacing8
    }

    config.background.customView?.tintColor = .red
    config.cornerStyle = .capsule
    config.baseForegroundColor = baseForegroundColor

    return config
  }
}
```