# For UIButton, I used title and image both. I want title should come first and than image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, user-interface

[image]

I want title "Alert" should come first and than image of Bell icon.

Comment: Assign `inset` to that button as per your requirement

Comment: see this it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100976/how-do-i-put-the-image-on-the-right-side-of-the-text-in-a-uibutton

Answer (score 1):

Possible Duplicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515998/iphone-uibutton-image-position)

Set the imageEdgeInset and titleEdgeInset to move the components around within your image. You could also create a button using those graphics that is full size, and use that as the background image for the button (then use titleEdgeInsets to move the title around).

Let me know if you still find any difficulty .